# drop down list in html data from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list in HTML, where the contents need to load from my MySQL DB using PHP.

I tried like the following; but no option is loading.

```
<strong> Select Data </strong> 
<select name="data1"> 
     <option value=""> NONE </option> 
<?php

$dd_res=mysql_query("Select relation FROM relation_names");
while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
{ 
     echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Also i tried like this:

```
$q="SELECT DISTINCT *relation FROM relation_names";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs))
{
    while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
    { 
        echo("<option value='$rd->id'>$rd->name</option>");
    }
}
```

But I don't know why these are not working, kindly help me.

i tried the code below as per comment.
but option names are not diplaying.[image: what i get when i try that code]

Comment: what php version do you have? [`mysql_query() - Warning: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: its 5.6 now, can you help me with pdo, i am new to php.

Comment: Hey, just try with mysqli_query for executing query & then check whether you will get the result or not, If you got the result then you can use mysqli_fetch_row for printing options.

Comment: i tried, but some problems as in image,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<strong> Select Data </strong> 
<select name="data1"> 
<option value=""> NONE </option> 
<?php
// Mysql db connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform queries 
$rs = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT relation FROM relation_names");
if($rs && mysqli_num_rows($rs))
{
     while($rd=mysqli_fetch_object($rs))
     { 
         echo("<option value='$rd->id'>$rd->relation</option>");
     }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_query()` insted of `mysql_query()`. Because `mysql_query()` extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

```
<strong> Select Data </strong> 
<select name="data1"> 
    <option value=""> NONE </option> 
<?php
    // Mysql db connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // Perform queries 
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT relation FROM relation_names");
    if($rs && mysqli_num_rows($rs))
    {
         while($rd=mysqli_fetch_object($rs))
         { 
             echo("<option value='$rd->id'>$rd->name</option>");
         }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
</select>
```

Refer below `mysqli` extentions

[mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[mysqli_connect_errno()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php)

[mysqli_connect_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

[mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

[mysqli_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: seems data is loading, but shows some error as first option, other options are empty.

Comment: corrected, thats my mistake * in the sql query, and name in echo options,
thank you

Comment: but how can i get the same as the option value too

Comment: please give detail description for what you exactly ask.

Comment: now i am getting dropdown list with the options as in database, but when i submit the form, there is no value for the selected option, ie, field in table is blank.